# Send data from C# form to mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to send data from my C# app to mysql.

The problem is that when I click the button nothing change in mysql.

Using this code:

```
private void updateUser()
{
    string connectionString = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=test;";
    // Update the properties of the row with ID 1
    string query = "UPDATE `users` SET `id` = 1, `meno`='Willy',`priezvisko`='Wonka',`email`='wonka@usa.com' WHERE id = 1";

    MySqlConnection databaseConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    MySqlCommand commandDatabase = new MySqlCommand(query, databaseConnection);
    commandDatabase.CommandTimeout = 60;
    MySqlDataReader reader;

    try
    {
        databaseConnection.Open();
        reader = commandDatabase.ExecuteReader();

        // Succesfully updated

        databaseConnection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Ops, maybe the id doesn't exists ?
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And the button to trigger it:

```
private void button_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    updateUser();
}
```

Comment: phpmyadmin is completely unrelated to this question, please don't confuse technologies - you only make it harder to understand what you want to do

Comment: You mean`meno` doesn't become `Willy` when you run this code?

Comment: The first cell of column `meno` become `Willy`, cell of column `priezvisko` become `Wonka` and so on. In this particular code, I want to update the first row (id = 1) of my table. And nothing is updated after I run this code.

Comment: *// Ops, maybe the id doesn't exists ?* - typically no database will throw an error if an update command affects 0 rows. Errors will be things like the server is down or you misspelled the table name. Use ExecuteNonQuery to run insert, update and delete queries and inspect the integer it returns; it's the number of rows the query affected. An update where the id didn't exist would return 0

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the actual query I wanted to do.

I changed it to:

```
string updateQuery = "INSERT INTO users(meno, priezvisko, email) VALUES ('Rene', 'Martin', 'h.halal@icloud.com');";
```

intead of:

```
string query = "UPDATE `users` SET `id` = 1, `meno`='Willy',`priezvisko`='Wonka',`email`='wonka@usa.com' WHERE id = 1";
```

It's caused by my improper knowledge.

Comment: At some point you'll want to vary the data you insert. Please **don't** write `"INSERT INTO users(meno, priezvisko, email) VALUES ('" + name + "', '" + fname + "', '"+ email +"');";`

Comment: Might want to rename the method to InsertUser, too..

Comment: I didn't write that. I wrote `string updateQuery = "INSERT INTO users(meno, priezvisko, email, hodnotenie) VALUES (@meno, @priezvisko,@email,@hodnotenie);";`. And I do not have that `private void updateUser()` anymore. Thanks to mention renaming the method but I was just copying some code from the internet and trying what will work.